# How do I add Asp.Net Server tags to JS and have them evaluated?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript file that I am including to a ASP.NET MVC view dynamically. This script sets some javascript variables whose values I would like to get from and HTML helper.

The following sets the js variables equal to the string containing the '<%'. How should this be formatted so that the server tags are evaluated when this file is included?
Thanks!

```
 var testPortal = ns.TestPortal;

testPortal.context = {};
testPortal.context.currentUserId = "<%= Html.GetCurrentUserId() %>";
testPortal.context.currentHwid = "<%=Model.Hwid %>"; 
testPortal.context.currentApplicationId = "<%= Html.GetCurrentApplicationId(Model.ProductName) %>";
```

**Update**

I am attempting to implement the solution provided to me by Darin below. The new action is working (tested it directly by typing url). However the when I try to create the script tag with a contentPlaceHolder on my view the action is never called. The script tag is never added to the view.

Can someone tell me why this might be??

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="DynamicIncludes" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Action("Index","Context", new{applicationName = Model.ProductName, hwid = Model.Hwid}) %>">
    alert("helloo");
</script>   
    </asp:Content>
```

Why is the above script not being added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use server side includes such as `<% %>` inside static `.js` files and that's because they are not processed by ASP.NET. What you could do instead is to define a controller action or a custom Http handler which will set the response `Content-Type` HTTP Header to `text/javascript` which could serve dynamic content. For example:

For example:

```
public ActionResult MyDynamicJs()
{
    return View();
}
```

and inside `MyDynamicJs.aspx` you could use server side tags:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<% Response.ContentType = "text/javascript"; %>
var testPortal = ns.TestPortal;
testPortal.context = {};
testPortal.context.currentUserId = "<%= Html.GetCurrentUserId() %>";
testPortal.context.currentHwid = "<%=Model.Hwid %>"; 
testPortal.context.currentApplicationId = "<%= Html.GetCurrentApplicationId(Model.ProductName) %>";
```

Now all that's left is to include this controller action somwhere:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Action("MyDynamicJs", "SomeController") %>"></script>
```

Comment: Could I do what you are suggesting using a partial view and eliminate the need to create a new action?

Comment: @Nick, no because views (partial or not) cannot be accessed directly. You always need a controller action to serve a view.

Comment: I'm trying this but for some reason the new action does not seemed to be called. I have created a controller called 'context' and have and action called, 'index'. I have the following script tage in my contentPlaceHolder <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Action("Index","Context", new{applicationName = Model.ProductName, hwid = Model.Hwid}) %>"></script>

Comment: Hmm.. it seems that when i add the script element to a ContentPlaceHolder in my view the action is never called.

Comment: If it's a big .js i wouldn't recommend doing so because dynamic generated content is not cached.

Comment: @Nick, a script tag cannot have a src tag and body content. It should look like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Action("Index", "Context", new { applicationName = Model.ProductName, hwid = Model.Hwid }) %>"></script>`.

Comment: @Maxim, it's normal that dynamic content is not cached, that's why it'called *dynamic* as it changes on each request, so caching it doesn't make sense. Of course it would be possible to append the proper caching HTTP headers inside the controller action if the content doesn't change often and so cache it on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the model is set up correctly and you have not done something really strange with the view, you should be able to populate the javascript in this manner, as it will only be seen as JavaScript when sent to the browser.

What errors or funkiness are you getting from the above code?